# Python: Appending items to a list

Tags: python-2.7, list

I want to append few items within a for loop to some lists. Currently what I am doing is,

```
listA = []
listB = []
listC = []
for i in range(0,100):
    listA.append(i)
for j in range(0,100):
    listB.append(j)
```

and so on. Is there any smarter way to do that?

Comment: `range` will output a list of elements within a range, so the example you provided makes little sense as you can do: `listA = range(0,100)` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to achieve this is:

```
listA = range(100)
listB = range(100)
listC = range(100)
```

or

```
listA, listB, listC = [range(100) for _ in range(3)]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I wanted a one liner and off course an optimal one. But I think second one works for me. Not sure about optimal though.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Well for sure it's faster than calling `range`, iterating through it and then appending the elements :)